# Children's Ghost/Horror short story collection from 1970s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel, ghost

I am looking for the name of a book I had as a child, it was a book of short stories, with ghost themes, nothing super scary, as I was younger than 9 or 10 when I read it. It would've been purchased in the 1970s. For some reason I thought of this book a few weeks ago, and asked my younger sister if she remembered it. She remembered the stories I mentioned, but couldn't recall the name either. The main story I remember had a ghost of a pirate (I think), and he was motionless, and had eyes like black marbles. The book had a few illustrations, and I recall there was one of this ghost (which creeped me out). Another story featured a soldier at a gate, but unfortunately that's all I remember. Just hoping someone out there might recall reading this! We already checked our parents' attic but didn't find it.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a book that I'm looking for as well. Do you remember if there was a story about a haunted merry-go-round?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest Mary Joe Clendenin's *[Galloping Ghosts](https://books.google.com/books?id=kFa7PS4E44sC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=ghost%20%22eyes%20like%20black%20marbles%22&source=bl&ots=P5Jwlw14Yx&sig=OSL9fZYx8rjhLws7Q6C61Z05BaU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIztT3zuzxyAIViDQ-Ch3Nuwbn#v=onepage&q=ghost%20%22eyes%20like%20black%20marbles%22&f=false)*. Her short story, "The Caretaker", refers to a man with the following description (emphasis mine):

> Dear Homer's wisps of gray hair, spread over the pillow, were smooth and carefully combed, forming a gruesome halo around the head with sunken *eyes like black marbles* which stared from the mummified skull. Dried thin lips were pulled back, as if the skin had shrunk in the drying process, revealing every tooth in a horrible smile. The sheet was pulled up and neatly tucked around the pajama clad body, except for one bony hand resting on the chest.

It's not a pirate, but you indicated that you were uncertain of that. I also haven't found any mention of a soldier in my Google Books search. However, it is an entry in a set of ghost stories which look to have been [originally published in 1977](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=6760204981&searchurl=an%3Dmary%20joe%20clendenin) and it's possible that Dr. Clendenin published her stories in other books.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a series of books by Ruth Manning Saunders.  There was "Ghosts, Ghosts, Ghosts"  and "Witches, Witches, Witches" etc.

Comment: And why would you think that either of these anthologies was the right one?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is part of the

"Scary Stories To Tell In The Dark"

set. I can't remember for certain. It isn't the first one (with Me Tie Dough-ty Walker and all that) but there was one called "More Scary Stories To Tell In The Dark" and it's ringing a bell pretty hard. Hope I'm right!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark